# No module named 'encodings' (Python3.5 - Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ply

i was coding with ply library for python3 in my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Raspbian, so i changed my default python version from 2.7 to 3.5 by using:

> alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5' and then
> $ . ~/.bashrc

it works good the first time, but with couples test, show me the error:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
> ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x76f73010 (most recent call first):

I tried to export the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH by using:

> export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ export
> PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/

and removing virtual environment files using:

> rm -rf venv virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/
>
> source env/bin/activate

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But it doesn't work...
Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: have you tried `python3 pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your "PYTHONHOME" and "PYTHONPATH"  env settings

On Linux

```
unset PYTHONHOME
unset PYTHONPATH
```

Then Try  again.